# customErrors is not wroking in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to ASP.net MVC. I have set customErrors to on in my web.config, and global.ascx.cs containd the following code:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

But when I throw an exception, I still see the yellow page error that shows stack trace. What else should I do? Any help is appreciated in advance.

**Edit**

Here is part of my web.config content:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc,     Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc,     Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: well. include your customErrors configuration in the question.

Comment: Is it giving an actual stack trace or is it just saying you should turn customErrors off?

Comment: it gives the actual stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to happen is that the application shows the default Error view, your customErrors config should be:

```
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />
```

If you're trying to achieve something else, please provide details.